# Create image for jenkins agent

Tags: docker, maven, kubernetes, jenkins, buildkite

I am trying to create a maven-based buildkit image for the jenkins agent.
If you create an image and run it as an agent, it takes infinite repetition.
I think the image is built incorrectly, but it asks to inspect the Dockerfile.

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:alpine as jnlp

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim as maven

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libfreetype6

FROM moby/buildkit

COPY --from=jnlp /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]
```

When only the maven agent is created without the "FROM moby/buildkit" statement, it runs without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer with a full example:

Your Dockerfile doesn't have references to the maven image.
If you need to have buildit in your final image you can install it by downloading from the GitHub or copying it from a docker image as you have for Jenkins agent.

I didn't test the docker file, but I hope you got the idea.

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:alpine as jnlp
FROM moby/buildkit as buildkit

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libfreetype6

COPY --from=buildkit /usr/bin/build* /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]
```

Update:

Per request in the comments, here is the version that might work for JDK8. You need to match all the components to have the same version to work:

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:latest-alpine-jdk8 as jnlp
FROM moby/buildkit as buildkit

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libfreetype6

COPY --from=buildkit /usr/bin/build* /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]
```

Comment: Then how do I put the buildkit on top of maven?

Comment: Added example to the answer

Comment: @dmytro-sirant, can you add example using jdk8?

Comment: @Gilberto the only difference in this case is what image you are using in FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim

Comment: @dmytro-sirant It doesn't work, because when I use jdk-8 it sets JAVA_HOME of both(maven and agent) to jdk-8, breaking the remote connection: UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/remoting/jnlp/Main

Comment: @Gilberto Ok, that makes sense. I updated the answer with additional changes, I hope now it works.

Comment: @DmytroSirant, thanks for help! But, as I've said it breaks the remote connection, because this change https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2021/08/17/docker-images-use-jdk-11-by-default/, both agent and controller must match the jvm version.

Comment: I was looking at for Dockerfile that uses an agent-jdk11 and put maven on jdk8 and at the end sets up the JENKINS_JAVA_BIN var to use jdk11. But even so I've got: permission denied